# In bash, how to use stdin to pass a stream (corresponding to a file) to a C binary?

Tags: c

In bash, If I have a file called **file1** how can I use `stdin` along with the binary corresponding to the following code in order to return the integer file descriptor corresponding to **file1** ?

```
int main(){

     return fileno(stdin);

}
```

Thank you

**p.s:**

I'm looking for a bash expression like this:

```
user:~$expression | ./binary
```

**p.s (bis):**

I had some difficulties to make a synthetic title, please tell me if you find a better one

Comment: `0` is the file descriptor (number) corresponding to `stdin`.  You'd use `./binary < file1` to make standard input correspond to `file1`.  If neither of those is relevant, you need to ask a clearer question.

Comment: If this is about the bash, remove the C tag and show your bash code. Otherwise this is not related to any shell.

Comment: Are you confusing file descriptors and inodes? As @Jonathan already was writing, the file descriptor of `stdin` always will be `0`, so your example program always has exit status `0`. If this indeed is your confusion, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9480568/find-inode-number-of-a-file-using-c-code.

Answer (score 2):

> In bash, If I have a file called **file1** how can I use `stdin` along with the binary corresponding to the following code in order to return the integer file descriptor corresponding to **file1** ?

You have an apparent misconception.  There is no single ***the*** file descriptor for any given file, nor indeed any file descriptor at all for a file that is not open.  File descriptors are per-process resources associated in each process with that process's open files.  The question is thus based on a false premise.

Furthermore, even if you redirect a process's standard input to come from **file1**, that does not identify `stdin` with **file1** in that process.  It merely means that you can read **file1**'s *contents* via `stdin`, once.  You cannot in that case gain any other information about **file1** from `stdin`, so even in a more general sense, the methodology you propose to use to get information about **file1** (other than its contents) is not viable.